# Как вывести все мини-карточки товаров в едином шаблоне в Magento?

Tags: cms, magento

Вообщем, задача такова:

Нужно вывести все мини-карточки товаров в едином шаблоне в Magento. Подскажите:

Или это сделать в виде модуля или нужно напрямую менять стили CSS самих этих карточек, подскажите знатоки!

Comment: Вы используете Magento 1 или 2? Чем не подошла страница списка товаров? Каков шаблон? Если вам просто нужно стилизовать страницу продукт листинга, то однозначно не нужен дополнительный модуль, все как правило решается в `.phtml` шаблонах т.к. информации о продуктах там хватает.